# Java: Serial Communication with USB port that is not listed as COM-port

Tags: java, serial-port, usb, communication

I am trying to establish a serial communication with a USB driven hardware. Unfortunately, the hardware is not recognized in the device manager under the listed COM ports. Therefore, it does not appear in my list and I don't know its COM port number. Instead the device is listed as another type of hardware.

How can I still connect with it?

I am currently using the following code to open my USB ports.

```
    public ArrayList<String> getPorts() {
CommPortIdentifier serialPortId;
ArrayList<String> portID = new ArrayList<String>();
Enumeration enumComm = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
while (enumComm.hasMoreElements()) {
    serialPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) enumComm.nextElement();
    if (serialPortId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        String portString= new String(serialPortId.getName());
        portID.add(portString);
    }
}
return portID;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I still connect with it?

You need a java binding to whatever driver the hardware actually uses, like LibUSB or hidapi.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Are LibUSB and hidapi Java tools to enable the communication with USB drivers?